# My simple switch statement doesn't work in C++

Tags: c++, switch-statement, case, break

I'm trying to write a very simple C++ switch statement, but despite reading the sample code from Absolute C++ , and other online examples It still doesn't output anything when I want it to. Why doesn't this code work?
(FIXED)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <random>

using namespace std;


int main()
{  
int HouseValue;
double AnnualInsuranceCost = 0;
cout << "Enter your total house value estimate: (rounded to nearest 50,000!)\n\n\n";
cin >> HouseValue;

switch (HouseValue)
{
    case 50000:
        AnnualInsuranceCost = 2000;
        break;

    case 100000:
        AnnualInsuranceCost = 3000;
        break;

    case 150000:
        AnnualInsuranceCost = 3500;
        break;

    case 200000:
        AnnualInsuranceCost = 3750; 
        break;

    case 250000:
        AnnualInsuranceCost = 3875;
        break;

}


cout << "\n\n\n\t\t    Your annual insurance cost will be: " << AnnualInsuranceCost << "\n\n\n\t\t\t";



return 0;
```

}

Comment: Put the final `cout` call out of the `switch`!!!

Comment: `AnnualInsuranceCost == 2,000;`
 --> `AnnualInsuranceCost = 2000;`

Comment: You use the equality operator in the `case` statements, not assignment.

Comment: You asked them to enter the house value to the nearest 50,000. So why are you testing for values 1, 2, 3, etc? SHouldn't you be testing for `50000`, `100000`, etc.?

Comment: This is a simple typographical error in entering integers: C++ does not "understand" thousand separators.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging the authors first C++ program, something He ought to do for himself.

Comment: @40two Pretty harsh! Half the SO questions seem to be from people who just started programming that day.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`). Then **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
case 5:
        cout << "250000";
        AnnualInsuranceCost = 3875;
        break;
}

cout << "Your annual insurance cost will be: " << AnnualInsuranceCost;
}
```

else the `cout` will be the part of `case 5`(*Although never reached.*)

Also change

```
AnnualInsuranceCost == 2,000;
```

to

```
AnnualInsuranceCost = 2000;
```

Similarly remove all the `comma` from your number and == is for comparison and = is for assignment.

Comment: @nwp:- Yes fixed that. A lot of bunch to fix were there. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to happen? You're prompting for a dollar figure, e.g. 100,000, and have **NO** `case` values that would actually match that. You also have no `default` case, so you can't even tell the user that nothing matched. A `switch/case` is just a fancy way of writing an extended `if else if else else if else` chain.

You would need something more like

```
switch(HouseValue)
   case 0:  ...
   case 50000: ...
   case 100000: ...
   ...
   default: ... if nothing else matches.
```

Comment: I didn't know the case had to be the value that pertains to it. Thanks.

Comment: `switch(foo) { case 'a': ...} ` is the equivalent of `if (foo == 'a')`.